# NodeJS - Promise.all() with array promise not return as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm developing a nodeJS application and I  have some following code :

```js
let all_result = await Promise.all([list_agrees,list_disagrees]);
    list_agrees = await Promise.all(list_agrees);
    list_disagrees = await Promise.all(list_disagrees);        

res.json({
    result_1:all_result,
    result_2: {
        list_agrees,
        list_disagrees
    }
});
```

Hi, here is what `list_agrees` and `list_disagrees` came from (and `UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor()` returns a promise)

```js
list_agrees = list_agrees.map(async function(id_user){ 
  return await UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req,id_user);
}); 

list_disagrees = list_disagrees.map(async function(id_user){ 
  return await UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req,id_user); 
});
```

now what I got when I received response is

```js
{
    "result_1": [
        [
            {}
        ],
        [
            {}
        ]
    ],
    "result_2": {
        "list_agrees": [
            {
                "avatar_thumbnail": null,
                "full_name": "Đạt Tô",
                "nick_name": "Gầy lọ"
            }
        ],
        "list_disagrees": [
            {
                "avatar_thumbnail": null,
                "full_name": "Gola User ",
                "nick_name": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't know why `Promise.all([list_agrees,list_disagress])` have not return the result as I expected!

Comment: `Promise.all(list_agrees)`  is `list_agrees` [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol)? Otherwise, you're using `Promise.all` incorrectly. There's a lot of odd variable name re-use going on here which is only going to make things very confusing

Comment: Agreed with Phil. Are those also arrays of promises?

Comment: Hi, here is what list_agrees and list_disagrees came from,and UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor() is a promise

`list_agrees = list_agrees.map(async function(id_user){
            return await UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req,id_user);
        });

        list_disagrees = list_disagrees.map(async function(id_user){
            return await UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req,id_user);
        });`

Comment: Yeah, I understand, that my mistake , thank a lot

Comment: there's a temporal dead zone issue as well ... you are using `list_agrees,list_disagrees` before either of them would be available to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works on an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) collection of promises.

Your issue is that both `list_agrees` and `list_disagrees` are arrays of promises and not promises themselves.

I would recommend something like this (without overwriting the original arrays)

```js
const agrees = Promise.all(list_agrees.map(id_user =>
    UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req, id_user)))
const disagrees = Promise.all(list_disagrees.map(id_user =>
    UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor(req, id_user)))
```

Now `agrees` and `disagrees` are each promises that will resolve when each `UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor()` call resolves.

There's no need to use async functions in the mapping since your `UserHelper.getUserBasicInfor()` returns a promise anyway.

Now you can use

```js
const all_result = await Promise.all([agrees, disagrees])
const [agrees_result, disagrees_result] = all_result
res.json({
  result_1:all_result,
  result_2: {
    list_agrees: agrees_result,
    list_disagrees: disagrees_result
  }
})
```